# Replicate HTTP video stream from vlc output

Tags: video-streaming

I have:

- videocomputer: a webcam and vlc who publish video stream on port `8080` with `cvlc -vvv v4l2:///dev/video1 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=mpga,vb=800,ab=128}:standard{access=http,mux=ogg,dst=:1234}'` (on ADSL with slow upload)
- webserver: a web server (with big upload)
- client1: vlc or whatever who want read video stream
- client2: vlc or whatever who want read video stream

I would like use `webserver` as entry point for `client1` and `client2`. Explanation:

If `client1` and `client2` are both reading video stream on `videocomputer`, it's internet connection will be saturated.

If `webserver` is connected to `videocomputer` video stream, `client1` and `client2` are connected to `webserver`. Internet connection of `videocomputer` saved.

My question is: Wich program can be replicate/make stream server in `webserver` ? If vlc can do that, how ?